# While trying to start my fastcgi-mono-server I get a permission error

Tags: sockets, nginx, mono, fastcgi, rhel7

I use this command to start my server :

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 -v /applications=www.testjet123.com:/:/usr/share/nginx/TestJet/ /socket=unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket
```

Everything is OK, the server is not stopped, but at the end of the output I get this error :

```
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.445497] Notice : Adding applications 'www.testjet123.com:/:/usr/share/nginx/TestJet/'...
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.454111] Notice : Registering application:
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.454177] Notice :     Host:          www.testjet123.com
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.454193] Notice :     Port:          any
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.454204] Notice :     Virtual path:  /
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.454216] Notice :     Physical path: /usr/share/nginx/TestJet/
[2017-11-13 06:29:00.466032] Error  : Error parsing permissions "". Use octal.
```

The `fastcgi_params` are default :

```
#ASP.NET
#fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "/usr/share/nginx/TestJet/";
#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

This is my `nginx` configuration :

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name testjet123.com www.testjet123.com  

    location / {
        root  /var/www/UI/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

However, when I use a TCP socket instead of a UNIX socket I do not get the error, see below :

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 -v /applications=www.testjet123.com:/:/usr/share/nginx/TestJet/  /socket=tcp:9000
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.160760] Notice : Adding applications 'www.testjet123.com:/:/usr/share/nginx/TestJet/'...
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.169121] Notice : Registering application:
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.169187] Notice :     Host:          www.testjet123.com
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.169202] Notice :     Port:          any
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.169213] Notice :     Virtual path:  /
[2017-11-13 06:36:09.169225] Notice :     Physical path: /usr/share/nginx/TestJet/
```

I am using RHEL 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `/filename=/tmp/fastcgi.socket` argument with `/socket=unix`, in place of the combined `/socket=unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket` argument.  I find that this has resolved the issue on debian based distros.

You'll need to set the permissions so that nginx (`www-data`) group has read & write access to the socket using : `chmod 660 /tmp/fastcgi.socket` & `chgrp www-data /tmp/fastcgi.socket`.

Although a bit off topic, my personal experience & reason for initially moving over to `unix` sockets from `tcp/ip` sockets was due to the connection between nginx and the mono service suddenly becomming disconnected after some period of time or number of requests.  Causing inbound requests to hang / fail.

I experienced the same issue with HyperFastCGI however, using `unix` sockets didn't help with either `HyperFastCGI` or `fastcgi-mono-server4`.

It turned out that it was dues to the fact I was using the latest packages directly from the mono developers repo, which installed mono version `5.10.1`.  Re-building the machine and only using the mono packages supplied by the debian based distro, which in installed mono version `4.6.2`, resolved my issue. No longer did the asp.net process detach or loose connection with the nginx service.

Additionally, according to : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/mono/ it's reccomended to use `unix` sockets :

> You could also bind it to a UNIX socket which is recommended.

Due to this recommendation I've continued to use `unix` sockets to communicate between nginx and the `fastcgi-mono-server4` service, and opted to not use `HyerfastCGI`.  I no longer experience any loss of connectivity or outage between nginx & the mono process; the connection is stable for many days and any number of requests.  In fact I've yet to experience any loss to date.  Also there's no form of memory leakage either using `fastcgi-mono-server` which other users have reported.